# Keypress detected in window but not in iframe

Tags: javascript

```
//detect print screen windows
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 44) {
    alert("printed");
        
  }
});
```

This code works for detecting prntscreen. However, if I click on my iframe, this code no longer works.

How do I make it so it works on my iframe too?

```
//detect print screen iframe
$("#left-container").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 44) {
    alert("printed");
        
  }
});
```

I've tried to add event listener to the container containing the iframe but that doesn't work either

How I'm creating the iframe:

```
 <div id = "left-container">
    <div id = "quiz1left">

    </div>
  </div>


<script>

var imgleft
var quiz1left    

var showQuizButton = document.getElementById("showQuiz");
showQuizButton.onclick = function(){

    
 imgleft = document.createElement("iframe");


 quiz1left = "Test 2.pdf";

imgleft.setAttribute("width", "100%");
imgleft.setAttribute("height", "100%");
imgleft.src = quiz1left

var src = document.getElementById("quiz1left");

src.appendChild(imgleft);
}

</script>
```

Comment: You have to declare the listener from within the `iframe` also

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Create a script inside the iframe and register the listener there

Comment: I've written the jquery i've tried and thought would work

Comment: @SaianshSingh how would I create a script inside the iframe. If you look at my code, I've written how I create the iframe. What code would I need to add to that?